# Laravel 10 with vue doesn't work for me, the app.js file can't find it

Tags: laravel, vue.js, openlayers

This line is giving me an error:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

[image: browser console error]

The system is running:

- Vite v4.3.5, ready in 1142 ms
- Laravel v10.9.0, plugin v0.7.6
- @vue/cli 5.0.8

##### My `codewelcome.blade`

[image: view-blade file]

When I add this line `@vite('resources/js/app.js')` in `welcome.blade.php`, it does not give me the error but the map is no longer visible, openlayers does not work...

Openlayers I add it to my site in `welcome.blade.php` with these lines.

[image: html head]

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are mixing `URL::xxxx` with `Vite::asset`.

This code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Should be:

```html
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

Or at least:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Please, do READ the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles

Comment: thanks matias the problem is that when placing that line @vite('resources/js/app.js').... the map stops working. I'll read more to see what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: What gets placed in that line in the final HTML you see? Do you get any errors on the browser console?